# An old man told me a story at lunch

Tags: riddle, cipher, lateral-thinking, story

Today I took my lunch break at my normal time, and sat in my usual location to eat. Nothing special, just a salad with tomatoes, swordfish, and tuna. While I sat there eating, and reading my book; an old man asked if he could join me. I nodded my head, and he sat down; what happened next was simply amazing. He told me a story, and it was quite a tale indeed. The only problem I had, and it wasn't that bad, was that every few words he would scream. Since I wasn't used to it, it startled me just about every time. I've decided I would share his story with you in the hopes that you enjoy it too!

**EIGHT** men ran a store long ago; they sold many beautiful treasures. **SEVEN** of which were quite renowned, and kept in **a** box lined with glass. **p**eople would come, from near and far to see these treasures; and often would leave, after buying trinkets. But **THREE** people made mistakes, the bought **w**hat was not for sale. The items weren't **U**sually available to the public, but the eight men who ran the store decided they wanted to show off their entire collections. Statues of lions, gold and silver, **X**ylophones, pianos, and **U**mberellas.

They really loved all of their treasures, because each was really q**u**ite exquisite. **J**ust in case you were **w**ondering, people have died for some of these treasures; haven't you ever heard the story of Neptune's rock? There's only ever been **ONE** found on the entire planet, and **Y**ou'd think it was truly from Neptune.

**S**ome people believe that Neptune's rock was crafted here on Earth, but others like to believe in the more supernatural stories. **M**y personal opinion is that the rock is just a hunk crap from space, but no one ever seems to want to believe that.

This next part is **V**ery important! He whispered the next part:

> keep to your faith.
>
> keep to your sight.

I have proof that the rock is of e**x**traterrestrial origin. Do you **n**eed the proof too? **W**ell don't expect me to make it easy on you, or **h**elp you.

He then slid me a piece of paper with some writing on it:

[image: hN89dfq8ng49wO7MGO9vHCQuKEpPDkkzcwp]

Look at the paper child, **o**ften the answers are hidden in plain sight. **S**ince you've listened to my story, I'd like to pay for your lunch. **H**onestly, you've been great company, but your salad could use some **z**est. You **c**ome with me, and I'll add some lemon, **PLUS** pay for the rest.

What is the hidden message the old man gave me?

**Hint**:

> I think you have to combine what you've found, in the order you found it. Also, my lunch was great by the way!

**Hint**:

> The algorithm, the key, and the encrypted text have all been found. I just need an answer at this point.

Comment: The writing looks like rot13('u a rvtug avar q s t fcnpr rvtug a t fcnpr sbhe avar j / mreb frira z t mreb avar i X V P D a / X R c C Q x x l p j c').

Comment: rot13(gurer ner ab fcnprf, gung'f whfg gur sbag).

Comment: It looks to me like rot13(u A rvtug avar q s d rvtug a t sbhe avar j B frira Z T B avar i U P D h X R c C Q x x m p j c).  I assume the letters and numbers are important, right @PerpetualJ?  Does the case matter?  And are those round characters "ohs" or "zeros"?

Comment: Casing is important; also, the round characters are letters, not numbers.

Comment: if you rot18 from cryptii you get ua34qst3at94jB2ztB4iUPDhXRcCxxlpjc here are the characters with rot18: hn89dfg8ng49wO7mgO9vHCQuKEpPkkycwp from the edit spot hN89dfq8ng49wO7MGO9vHCQuKEpPDkkzcwp with rot18 is uA34qsd3at94jB2ZTB4iUPDhXRcCQxxmpjc

Comment: The image name is 5axj5.jpg.  Kind of looks like '5x5' with letters 'a' and 'j' in there.  FAITH and SIGHT are both 5 letter words.  Maybe either the characters in bold or the characters in the note (or both) need to be in some sort of 5 by 5 grid and decoded?... I kind of want to meet this old guy, and have him make comments on my salad... :)

Comment: The characters in bold (yelled by the old man) are: 87ap3wuXUuJw1YSMVxnWhoSHzc+

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, but maybe

> We use Twofish algorithm because of the lunch with swordfish and tuna.
>
> The encrypted text will be:
> 87ap3wUXUuJw1YSMVxnWhhN89dfq8ng49wO7MGO9vHCQuKEpPDkkzcwpoSHzc+
> Because the hint said to combine it the way we found it.
>
> But I'm still lost with the key, my guess was tomatoes but I don't think that was it.

Comment: You're correct on the algorithm and the key. The encrypted text is wrong. +1 Keep up the good work!

Comment: Ooh. I thought I had the key wrong. Haha. Does the filename of the image have anything to do with the encrypted text?

Comment: The file name has nothing to do with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an actual answer but I will throw away whatever i have got, since it wouldn't be nice to post this in comments ***if*** it contains correct steps to reach the answer.

Cipher:

> Since the yelled words end with a plus and also from the hint it feels like the cipher text is combination of both yelled words and text image. it is: **87ap3wuXUuJw1YSMVxnWhoSHzc+hN89dfq8ng49wO7MGO9vHCQuKEpPDkkzcwp** .

Algorithm:

> The lunch might be pointing us to the encryption algorithm. Tuna can relate to Tunafish,  swordfish is already a fish, I guess it should be some cipher related to the word **Fish**.

Also The other words the man whispered

> *keep to your faith.
> keep to your sight*.
>  This should be leading s to the key. I guess either **Keep** is the key OR faith and Sight - the only uncommon words in the both lines of the riddle should produce the key.

Comment: For the most part you're doing great! +1 From me! However, read the hint more carefully in regards to the encrypted text. As for the algorithm, you're spot on, there is one in particular. The words the man whispered are a red herring and have nothing to do with the key. The key has also been hinted at and you've already found other information near it.